# jest onChange Unit test - React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, onchange

I have this function onChange for which i write to a unit test.

```
<Checkbox
          onChange={ () => {
                if (this.props.showTab) {
                      this.showBox();
                   }
                  this.props.handleChange();
        }}/>

showBox() {
        this.setState({ showBox: true });
    }
```

I have tried with

```
it('onChange', () => {
        const component = mount(<View
            showTab={true}
            handleChange= {handleChange}
            />);
        const instance = component.instance();
        const mockSetStateFn = jest.fn();
        instance.setState = mockSetStateFn;
        component.find('input').at(0).simulate('change');
        component.instance().showBox();
        expect(instance.setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ showBox: true });
    });
```

It gives error “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead." How do i test it?

Comment: I think the issue is with using simulate on `.at(0)`. Try to run `component.find('input').simulate('change')` instead

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In this unit test you shouldn't find the input if you render the Checkbox. You should make it like this:

```js
component.find(Checkbox).invoke('onChange')()
```